# how to connect remote mysql database from local machine using jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

i have tried to connect from Jmeter to external mysql server using JDBC sampler. But I am getting erros. its possible to connect to the local mysql server.I am confused how to connect jmeter from my local machine to server database in other machine using JDBC CONNECTION

Comment: Show logs or anything you've tried

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you remote MySQL server is accepting remote connections. Locate `bind-address` line in *my.cnf* file and set it to listen on all interfaces:

   ```
   bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
   ```

   See [Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-connecting.html) for more details. You will need restart MySQL server in order to pick up any changes made in *my.cnf* file
2. Make sure your operating system firewall on MySQL server side allows incoming connections to MySQL server TCP port (default is `3306`).
3. Verify that you able to hit port 3306 with a [telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) or equivalent

If you will be still experiencing problems - update your question with JDBC Request sampler output and *jmeter.log* file contents. I would also recommend checking out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) to learn more about the concept of databases load testing using JMeter

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am very new to Jmeter. So could you please share the prerequisites for the server machine for jdbc connection

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to that server using MySQL Workbench or another tool just use the below config for JMeter.

Just remember that you need to have mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar (or another version of it) under apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ folder.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!